# Correct name of a 12v power strip socket

Tags: power-supply, identification, 12v

I'm trying to locate one of these black strips:

[image]

I purchased it as a component part in the uk but they don't sell them anymore.

It supplies 12v lights (attached to the output of a transformer.

Any ideas what the official name for one is?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What are they called / or any idea where I can get one from?!

Comment: This type of question is off topic

Comment: Electrical? Which forum would I be better posting in?

Comment: [Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) is off-topic.

Comment: "Where to buy" questions are off topic. "What is it called" questions are often accepted.

Comment: I'm trying to identify a type of electrical part. I don't know what the full technical description is so I am asking for assistance. Whether I purchase it, write a thesis or add it to an electrical design afterwards is irrelevant.

Comment: It seems to be more a type of connector than a power strip. Pictures showing the white connectors might help. State whether it came with a DC power supply or just a connector at the end of the black cord would help.

Comment: Note that the close notice says "please edit the question."

Comment: Hi Charles, I purchased it (without the PSU or cabling) as a component for 12v DC down lights (the type you put under your kitchen counter).

Comment: Since you edited your question, I've voted to reopen. I also edited your title to better match the spirit of the updated question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'm still none the wiser. These adaptors are commonplace (there seems to be two types of connections typically available for low voltage DC supplies, this type being one of them.

Comment: For what it is worth, the white plastic connectors look suspiciously like some of molex's higher current ranges. I don't think it's easy to identify either the connector or the strip without dimensions and ideally an estimate of the conductor surface area/wire gauge going in. You might like to try looking on the device for any further clues, such as 'hirose', 'HRS', or any sort of string of digits that could be a product number.